# ActiveJob and Sidekiq jobs stuck in enqueued

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sidekiq, rails-activejob

So I just migrated to Rails 5.1.4 and I'm trying to make Active Job work, but the jobs are just stuck in the queue and never processed.

- rails: 5.1.4
- ruby: 2.4.3
- sidekiq: 5.0.5
- redis: 4.0.1

sidekiq.yml

```
---
:verbose: true
:concurrency: 5
:timeout: 60
development:
  :concurrency: 25
staging:
  :concurrency: 50
production:
  :concurrency: 5
:queues:
  - default
  - [high_priority, 2]
```

sidekiq.rb

```
Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
  config.redis = {url: ENV['ACTIVE_JOB_URL'], network_timeout: 5}
end

Sidekiq.configure_client do |config|
  config.redis = {url: ENV['ACTIVE_JOB_URL'], network_timeout: 5}
end
```

Here the is how I perform the task from the rails console:

```
TestJob.perform_later
```

TestJob.rb content:

```
class TestJob < ApplicationJob
  queue_as :default

  def perform(*args)
    Rails.logger.debug "#{self.class.name}: I'm performing my job with arguments: #{args.inspect}"
  end
end
```

The jobs are just stuck in the queue and never processed:

[image]

Comment: First, stop your Sidekiq server. Then, from the command line, type `redis-cli`, then `flushall`, then `exit`. This will destroy everything that's in the redis database and let you start over. Then restart Sidekiq.

Answer (score 4):

Have you started the worker, eg in development it might be:

```
bundle exec sidekiq
```

If in production Heroku should do this for you, if you have configured your **Procfile**, eg:

```
web: bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb
worker: bundle exec sidekiq
```

You can also use your Procfile in development with **foreman**, eg:

```
foreman start -f Procfile
```

Comment: It works when I run that command. How can I modify sidekiq.yml to support prefixes, for example, there is this option for active_job config.active_job.queue_name_prefix  = "#{ENV['ACTIVE_JOB_QUEUE_PREFIX']}_#{Rails.env}". How can I name queues for each environment?

Comment: You cannot.  Use a different Redis database for each environment, e.g. `config.redis = { db: 1 }`